# How to tell the user clicked the cancel in filename selection dialog?

Tags: c++, qt

If I use the following code to get a fileName.

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Load File"), ".", tr("Waypoint File (*.txt)"));
```

And instead of choosing a file, the user clicked the cancel button. What will be the value of fileName, will it be OS dependent? Or how could I tell the user clicked the cancel?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> This is a convenience static function that returns an existing file
>   selected by the user. If the user presses Cancel, it returns a **null**
>   **string**.